# How to Post Dictionary<> object using UnityWebRequest in Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-game-engine

I want to post `Dictionary<>` object using `UnityWebRequest` in Unity. I can post it as a JSON string, but I want it to post it as a `Dictionary<string, string>` object as `UnityWebRequest.Post()` accepts `Dictionary<>` object that is `UnityWebRequest.Post(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> formFields)`. I am getting `NullReferenceException` in ASP.NET Web Project. Probably I am not able to Post User object properly. Am I missing something?

**Here is my Unity code:**

```cs
IEnumerator PostData()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> UserDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Id", "009" },
        { "UserName", "John" }
    };

    UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Post(InputField.text, UserDetails);
    yield return req.SendWebRequest();
    
    if (req.isNetworkError)
        print("Error: " + req.error);
    if (req.isDone)
        print(req.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

**Here is my ASP.NET Core Web API Using Entity Framework Core:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string AddNewUser([FromBody]User user)
{
    Context.UsersData.Add(user);
    Context.SaveChanges();
    return "Data Inserted for Id: " + user.Id;
}
```

**User model in ASP.NET Core**

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The post request is posting it as url encoded fields aka ?Id=009&Username=John. Its not posting a JSON object.

Comment: @John, I know, but I don't want to post as a JSON object, instead I want to Post directly as a Dictionary<> object.

Comment: Adjust your desires and follow what the API allows.

Comment: @John wouldn't that rather be the GET protocol?

Comment: @derHugo its the urlencoded method of sending data. Both GET and POST can do it, but only POST can also take multi-line body with special characters.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin you can probably do something like AddNewUser(string Id, string Username) instead

Comment: @John oh I see .. isn't this somehow breaking the reason why you would even use POST? ^^ sounds like that Dictionary overload should be avoided then?

Comment: You can use POST to send urlencoded data if the data string is too long since some browsers and servers block it with GET requests. The issue isn't that he wants to use dictionaries. Its that hes making it harder on himself by not just using a JSON object and posting the formatted string as the body content.

Comment: @John, It's not about making things harder, When Unity provides a method to post Dictionary<> object, isn't there any method on how we can achieve it?

Comment: I already told you what you can do. Its not passing an object, just fields. So adjust your function to accept fields if its even possible.